# I am trying the boxes to align using css,I gave height and width but still one of the divs are shifting up

Tags: css

I am trying to align the three boxes with class "nameplate".
If the text length increases in one of the boxes.
The other 2 boxes are shifting slightly downward.
It is working as expected when the text are of equal length.
I tried to add height to it but it is not working.
Please see snapshot.
I want to align the boxes even if text length is unequal.

[Snapshot_Box shifting Up][The behavior required]

```css
h1 {
    color:red;
}

.green {
    color:rgb(14, 231, 68);
}

#yellow {
    color:yellow;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px
    
}

nav {
    
    text-align: center;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:30px;
    font-size: larger;
    
   
    height: 30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin:60px 10px;
    /*background-color: chartreuse;*/
}
}

.boxed {
    margin:0px;
}
    

.container .boxed p {
    background-color: coral;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border:2px soloid rgb(224, 64, 6);
    width:150px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

 .nameplate {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:300px;
    margin:0px 20px;
    height: 500px;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxed">
            <p>lorem ipsum </p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxed">
            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:29</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:35</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:29</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.nameplate`

Try this code:

```css
h1 {
    color:red;
}

.green {
    color:rgb(14, 231, 68);
}

#yellow {
    color:yellow;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px
    
}

nav {
    
    text-align: center;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:30px;
    font-size: larger;
    
   
    height: 30px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin:60px 10px;
    /*background-color: chartreuse;*/
}
}

.boxed {
    margin:0px;
}
    

.container .boxed p {
    background-color: coral;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border:2px soloid rgb(224, 64, 6);
    width:150px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}

 .nameplate {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:300px;
    margin:0px 20px;
    height: 500px;
   
   
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxed">
            <p>lorem ipsum </p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxed">
            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:29</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:35</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem some extra text </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="nameplate">
                <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                <hr />
                <h2>Age:29</h2>
                <h3>Address: lorem ipsum lorem</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```